# Behavior of a solution of the differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we are given function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ being twice differentiable. What is more $f$ satisfies: $$(1) \quad f''(x)-5f'(x)+6f(x)\ge0$$ for all $x\in [0,+\infty)$, $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$. I am asked to prove $f(x)\ge 3e^{2x}-2e^{3x}$.

**My approache:** Let $g(x)=3e^{2x}-2e^{3x}$, than it satisfies all conditions on $f$ with equality in $(1)$. Now if we define $h=f-g$ it satisfies $(1)$, $h(0)=0$,  $h'(0)=0$ and we are forced to show that $h(x) \ge 0$.

Yet I have troubles with proving that, your help is mostly welcome as well as hints to your solutions.

Comment: sorry there should be +, thanks.

Comment: Hint: We may write the ODE with initial conditions $h(0)=h'(0)=0$ as:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\begin{array}{c} u \\ v\end{array}\right) \geq  \left(\begin{array}{cc}5 & -6\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} u \\ v\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio how do you mean that inequality ?

Comment: Just put $v(x) = f(x), v'(x)=f'(x)=u(x), f''(x)=u'(x)$.

Comment: yea I see that, but you mean that the inequality between that vectors is in what sense, that their coordinates satisfie it (that's true, but I don't see what it gives) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since 
$$(f'(x)-2f(x))'-3(f'(x)-2f(x))\ge 0$$
let 
$$G(x)=e^{-3x}(f'(x)-2f(x))$$
then
$$G'(x)\ge  0\Longrightarrow G(x)\ge G(0)=-2$$
so
$$f'(x)-2f(x)\ge -2e^{3x}$$
so
$$(f(x)e^{-2x})'\ge -2e^x$$
Let
$$H(x)=f(x)e^{-2x}+2e^x\Longrightarrow H'(x)\ge 0$$
so
$$H(x)\ge H(0)=3$$
so
$$f(x)\ge 3e^{2x}-2e^{3x}$$